# Why are double semicolon sometimes needed after "let", and sometimes not?

Tags: syntax, ocaml

The following two let definitions are connected by a new line, which works

```
# let x = 1 + 2 * 3
  let y = (1 + 2) * 3;;
val x : int = 7
val y : int = 9
```

But the following fails.

```
let x = 3 
    

print_string "hello" ;;
```

Error:

```
let x = 3 
    
    print_string "hello" ;;
Error: This expression has type int
This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

The above can be fixed by putting two semicolons. But why sometimes we need two semicolons after "let", and sometimes we do not need them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml is white space insensitive. In particular, newline never affects the reading of the code (for the compiler). Let's thus rewrite your two examples without newlines.
The first one reads as

```ml
let x = 3 let y = 1
```

which is fine: we have two definitions following each other, the `let` at the start of the definitions allow us to separate the two definitions.

However, the second example reads as

```ml
let x = 3 print_string "hello"
```

Here, we are applying the integer `3` to the `print_string` function which is an error.
Thus if we want to have a toplevel expressions after a definition like `let x = 3`, we need to separate the two with `;;`.

```ml
let x = 3 ;; print_string "hello"
```

Or we can transform the toplevel expression into a definition that does not define any new variable with

```ml
let x = 3 let () = print_string "hello"
```

Comment: So, ";;" is a separator, not ";"? Always confused about that...

Comment: `;` is an operator on expressions that takes two expressions `a;b`, compute the result of the first one discards  its result and returns the second. `;;` is a separator between toplevel expressions or definitions which is only needed before a toplevel expression.

Comment: Please note that `;;` should never be needed in a full OCaml program.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, `;;` is mostly used to indicate to the REPL that you're done entering your code and would like it to evaluate what you entered. It is *never* needed in OCaml programs. As long as your OCaml programs don't have "toplevel expressions".

This is a toplevel expression in `file.ml`:

```ml
print_endline "hello"
```

This is a proper toplevel definition in `file.ml`:

```ml
let () = print_endline "hello"
```

An OCaml file can be a single toplevel expression, a bunch of toplevel definitions, or any mix of both—as long as they're separated with `;;`.
The mix-of-both-separated-with-`;;` is unidiomatic. It is preferable that you don't have toplevel expressions floating around in your program. And while a single-expression program is possible, it's not quite scalable. Thus, idiomatic OCaml programs are a series of toplevel definitions.

Note that, unlike `let binding = expr` being a definition, `let local_binding = expr₁ in expr₂` is an expression. It too shouldn't be floating around without an accompanying toplevel definition.

Meaning, these are wrong:

```ml
let a = 5

let b = 6 in
print_int (a + b)

(* same as: let a = 5 (let b = 6 in print_int (a + b)) *)
(* 5 is not a function, it cannot be applied to the expression following it *)
```

```ml
let a = 5 in
let () = print_int a
(* ^-- not an expression, but a binding *)
(* same as: (let a = 5 in let () = print_int a) *)
```

And these are correct

```ml
let a = 5
let b = 6
let () = print_int (a + b)
(* all toplevel bindings *)
```

```ml
let () =
  let a = 5 in
  let b = 6 in
  print_int (a + b)
(* a single toplevel binding *)
(* same as: let () = (let a = 5 in (let b = 6 in print_int (a + b))) *)
```

Another note, you'll see some programs in the wild where even though `;;` is not needed, every let binding is terminated with `;;`. This is just a style, and it's not too popular because it perpetuates the misconception that `;;` is required. The argument for it is that it may produce better syntax errors (maybe it did historically). Also, tutorials may use this style to aid you in copy-pasting definitions directly to the REPL. I find that choice dubious personally, considering the toplevel is more friendly to a batch of definitions terminated with a single `;;` than it is to a batch of definitions separated with `;;`.

In any case, I hope this gives you some intuition on how OCaml parses files.